# how to call constructor of javascript from Angular js like below ng-init i have defined variables but call constructor in service.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to convert this code into angular js this code is in core  i want to to call core javascript constructor from angular js . i had already defined how to call service constructor in core its working fine in developement but seriously i dont know how to call constructor from angular js if any one have any idea please suggest

in data-ng-init i want to call service constructor like :- new service

javascript core

```
 (function(){
    service = new service({
            on_connection_init : connectingIndicator,
            on_connection_inprogress : connectingProgress,
            on_connection_complete : connectedIndicator,
            on_connection_close : closedIndicator
    });

     service.submit("service_demo_keys", {});

});


/*angular js*/

 var app = angular.module('service', []);

   app.controller('sendtocluster', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "connecting to service....";

});



   <div ng-app="service" ng-controller="sendtocluster"  data-ng-init="names=[{on_connection_init : 'connectingIndicator',on_connection_inprogress : 'connectingProgress',on_connection_complete : 'connectedIndicator',on_connection_close : 'closedIndicator'}]">




        <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
        <h1>Response:-  {{name}}</h1>


       <li data-ng-repeat="myObject in names"> 
    {{myObject.on_connection_init}} -    

    {{ myObject.on_connection_inprogress}}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with $window object..

You can inject the code just before the angular registered. Or try to load before angular loded in your index.html.

```
// global variable outside angular var variable1 = true; var app = angular.module('myapp', []); app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) { $scope.variable1 = $window.variable1; }]);
```